# I can not find out a formula for this :

Tags: integer-partitions, set-partition

Between 1 and 45, (and included, 1 and 45) ;

How many --5 set combinations-- are there from 1 to 45 with a total of 155?
*What are these combinations ?

(PS: each number can only be written once )

In Example:
1 + 31 + 34 + 44 + 45 = 155  or  13 + 26 + 35 + 37 + 44 = 155  or 14 + 25 + 35 + 37 + 44 = 155

I am new here, and I could not know which topic belongs to this question...

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for partitions.

Comment: Maybe try using elementary addition principles and summations.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I could not find out the answer. I looked at the partitions but I could not do it ..

Comment: @Vaibhav I tried things I know and I could not succeed.. Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0):

If $\ P(n,m,s)\ $ is the number of partitions of $\ n\ $ with exactly $\ s\ $ unequal summands between $1$ and $\ m\ $, then what you're looking for is $\ P(155,45,5)\ $. I doubt if there's any simple formula for the general value of $\ P(n,m,s)\ $, but once you specify particular values of $\ n\ $, $\ m\ $ and $\ s\ $, you can use the recursion
$$
 P(n,m,s)=\sum_{i=1}^{\min\left(m,n+1-\frac{s(s-1)}{2}\right)}P(n-i,i-1,s-1)
$$
to calculate its value.  According to my calculations $\ P(155,45,5)=6557\ $.

[Here's](https://onlinegdb.com/BkIsD8MRS) a C program to print all $6557$ partitions with the required properties.  Only the last $11$ or so lines of output will be visible in the window below the program listing. However, if you click on the clipboard icon in the bar immediately above the output window, all of the output will be copied to your computer's clipboard, from where it can be pasted to a location where all of it will be viewable.

Comment: I could not do it. I went to page but it didnt work out... :(

Comment: I went to page, but it asked which language and I tried all of the languages but it does not work... :(

Comment: @Donitte Gonzales Unfortunately I hadn't made the code shareable, so apparently I was the only person who could see it.  I've now done so and updated the link. Try it now.

Comment: But I didnt understand it. When I go to the page and click run, it does not show the possibilities or how many combinations matching this criteria. What is the point of putting that there ? I am lost :(

Comment: so is it 11178 combinations ? If it is so, what are these combinations ? This was my question...  :(

Comment: I've just discovered an error in the program, so the $11,178$ isn't actually correct.  Your original question was *not* "what are these combinations",  but *how many* of them there are.   [You added](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3474449/revisions)  the request for the combinations themselves only about $30$ minutes ago.  Listing the partitions themselves requires a somewhat more complex recursion than merely counting them.

Comment: I was thinking the result of it and I forgot to write it so after your answer, I wrote it to correct my question in that way. Besides, I would be happy to see what are these combinations.. Sad to see it was wrong by the way.. I am not qualified and educated for math, except, I can solve some equations problems but I have no idea of the answer of the question I asked because I am not educated on related topic... I do appreciate for your try and thank you again...

Comment: I believe I've now corrected the bugs in the program. It now returns the value $10,993$ for the value of $\ P(155,45,5)\ $.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But I need all these numbers sets.

Comment: I have now written a program to print a list of all the partitions with the specified properties, and added a link to it at the bottom of my answer.  The number of partitions it finds is the same as the number calculated by the other program, thus confirming that the latter is unlikely to contain any further errors.

Comment: It looks fine except, (PS: each number can only be written once; I have written that in my question ), it writes the numbers again... It should write each number just once.. :( I think the first version you made was correct except writing the combinations...

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the condition that there should be no repeated summands, so much of the material in my original answer was irrelevant to the question you actually asked.  I've now updated the program so it only prints out those partitions without repeated numbers, and modified my answer accordingly.